# I need to combine 2 queries postgis

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have 2 queries:

1st query :

```
SELECT ST_AsText( ST_MakeLine(sp) )
FROM
(SELECT
  ST_PointN(geom, generate_series(1, ST_NPoints(geom))) as sp
FROM
   -- extract the individual linestrings
  (SELECT (ST_Dump(ST_Boundary(geom))).geom
   FROM geometriess
   ) AS linestrings
) AS segments;
```

In the table there is : "POLYGON((0 0,1 0,1 1,0 1,0 0))"

After this query there will be : "LINESTRING(0 0,1 0,1 1,0 1,0 0)"

And 2nd query :

```
 with line as (select geom from geometries)
select ST_X(ST_PointN(geom,num)) as x, 
       ST_Y(ST_PointN(geom,num)) as y 
from line,
   (select generate_series(1, (select ST_NumPoints(geom) from line)) as num) 
as series;
```

it splits linestring to points x and y.

I need to combine them, but I don't know how.

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do exactly. You seem to be dumping points out of a line and then recombining them?

Comment: I want to get from polygon st_x and st_y

Comment: I have posted an answer, that will pull points out of the boundaries of polygons, if that is what you are asking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following test table creates two polygons, with different numbers of points, combines them together, and then grabs each point of the boundary using generate_series with st_npoints to iterate through each polygon.

```
create table test (id serial, geom geometry);
insert into test (geom) values (ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((0 0, 0 1, 1 1, 1 0, 0 0))'));
insert into test (geom) values (ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((100 100, 100 200, 200 200, 250 300, 200 100, 100 100))'));


with dumped as (select (st_dump(geom)) as dump from 
      (select st_collect(geom) as geom from test) g),
    points as (select (dump).path, st_npoints((dump).geom) as npoints, (dump).geom from dumped),
    polygons as (select path[1] as polygonid, 
                 st_boundary(geom) as geom, 
                 generate_series(1,npoints) as x from points)
 select polygonid, 
        st_x(st_pointn(geom,x)), 
        st_y(st_pointn(geom,x)) 
 from polygons;
```

returns:

```
 polygonid | st_x | st_y 
-----------+------+------
     1 |    0 |    0
     1 |    0 |    1
     1 |    1 |    1
     1 |    1 |    0
     1 |    0 |    0
     2 |  100 |  100
     2 |  100 |  200
     2 |  200 |  200
     2 |  250 |  300
     2 |  200 |  100
     2 |  100 |  100
```